# faster search for a substring through large document

Tags: spring, database, postgresql, search

I have a csv file of more than 1M records written in English + another language. I have to make a UI that gets a keyword, search through the document, and returns record where that key appears. I look for the key in two columns only.

Here is how I implemented it:

First, I made a postgres database for the data stored in the CSV file. Then made a classic website where the user can enter a keyword. This is the SQL query that I use(In spring boot)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE %:keyword% OR col2 LIKE %:keyword%;
```

Right now, it is working perfectly fine, but I was wondering how to make search faster? was using SQL instead of classic document search better?

Comment: Have you considered ElasticSearch?

Comment: ElasticSearch is good, but  you should use also Postgres, but in a different manner: try to look at [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html)

Comment: that was so informative and interesting! thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the document is only searched once and thrown away, then it's overhead to load into a database.  Instead can search the file directly using the nio parallel search feature which uses multiple threads to concurrently search the file:

```
    List<Record> result = Files.lines("some/path")
            .parallel()
            .unordered()
            .map(l -> lineToRecord(l))
            .filter(r -> r.getCol1().contains(keyword) || r.getCol2().contains(keyword))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

NOTE: need to provide the lineToRecord() method and the Record class.

If the document is going to be searched over and over again, then can think about indexing the document.  This means pre-processing the document to suit the search requirements.  In this case it's keywords of col1 and col2.  An index is like a map in java, eg:

```
Map<String, Record> col1Index
```

But since you have the "LIKE" semantics, this is not so easy to do as it's not as simple as splitting the string by white space since the keyword could match a substring.  So in this case it might be best to look for some tool to help.  Typically this would be something like solr/lucene.

Databases can also provide similar functionality eg: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html

Answer (score 1):

For LIKE queries, you should look at the [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) index type with the gin_trgm_ops operator class.  You shouldn't need to change query at all, just build the index on each column.  Or maybe one multi-column index.